# Wrap part of text into new element tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text into a `<span>` tag. I want wrap part of that text into another element tag with an ID which is not in the base HTML code.
Since I cannot modify the base HTML code, I'm forced to use `JavaScript/JQuery` to do so.

I have this HTML code:

```
<span id="my_span">John<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="John" id="my_input1">
<br>Smith<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="Smith" id="my_input2">
</span>
```

I want to add an `<a>` tag with ID to the texts within that span. The text I want to wrap is dynamic so I cannot use the value inside as such to search for it and target it. The HMTL code should look as shown below after the `JavaScript/JQuery` code is applied:

```
<span id="my_span"><a id="added_a_tag1">John</a><input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="John" id="my_input1">
<br>
<a id="added_a_tag2">Smith</a><input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="Smith" id="my_input2">
</span>
```

Sounds simple but I haven't been able to achieve it.

I will need to target those newly added IDs for something else later on.

I appreciate your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery's `.contents()` to get the contents of your `<span>`. Then filter to only text nodes (nodeType of 3). Then loop through each, and wrap it with an `<a>` tag if it is not empty. (If you don't perform the trim and empty check, you'll end up with `<a>` tags for any newline characters inside your span).

See the working example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('#my_span').contents()
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3
    })
    .each(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).text()).length > 0) {
        $(this).wrap('<a href id="added_a_tag_' + (++count) + '"></a>');
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="my_span">
  John<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="John" id="my_input1">
  <br>
  Smith<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="Smith" id="my_input2">
</span>
```

Comment: this works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have another `<span>` element with a know ID around your text by default.

```
<span id="name_1">John</span>
```

Now change the element type dynamically

```
var currentText = $("#name_1").innerHTML;
 $("#name_1").replaceWith('<a id="dynamic_1">' + currentText + '</a>');
```

You can change an index suffix in the id within a loop if you have a series of inputs like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.map()` , `Array.prototype.forEach()` , `.html()` , `.replace()`

```js
$("#my_span").map(function() {
  // split new line character of `#my_span` `.textContent`
  var txt = this.textContent.split("\n").filter(Boolean);
  // iterate each `txt`
  txt.forEach(function(val, index) {
    $(this).html(function(_, html) {
      // replace `val` with `a` element
      return html.replace(val, $("<a />", {
        "text": txt[index],
        "id": "added_a_tag" + (index + 1),
        "href": "#"
      })[0].outerHTML)
    })
  }.bind(this))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="my_span">John<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="John" id="my_input1">
<br>Smith<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="Smith" id="my_input2">
</span>
```